# Quit application on MenuStripItem press

Tags: c#, messagebox, quit, menustrip, eventargs

I'm pretty new to C#, and I ran today into a bug.

I'm making a Windows Form Application in Visual C# in Visual Studio 2013.
In the "Form1 [Design]" tab of the project, I added a MenuStrip, in which I then created a "New" and "Quit" item.

When I press the "Quit" button (identified here as quitterLapplicationToolStripMenuItem, automatically generated by VS2013) I have this code to run :

```
private void quitterLapplicationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, CancelEventArgs c, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult resultat = MessageBox.Show("Close?" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Really ? No more notifications ?", "Closing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (resultat == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Prog stopped correctly", "Quit");
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        c.Cancel = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }
}
```

And when I try to run this, an error appears, saying :

> No overload for 'quitterLapplicationToolStripMenuItem_Click' matches
>   delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Oh, and here's what line is causing the error :

```
this.quitterLapplicationToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.quitterLapplicationToolStripMenuItem_Click);
```

What can I do ? I'm stuck and I have not found anything that could help me (and that I could understand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
(object sender, CancelEventArgs c, EventArgs e)
```

with

```
(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The parameters on the method are not correct: you've got a sort of mish-mash of two different method signatures.

It's either supposed to be:

```
private void quitterLapplicationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, CancelEventArgs c)
```

or

```
private void quitterLapplicationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now, `c.Cancel` is causing me an error because there is no 'Cancel' definition in EventArgs. Is there another way to cancel the action to close a program ?

Comment: Nevermind, just removing the c.Cancel args did what I wanted to do.